# Connecting R to embedded H2 database on RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, h2

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to connect my R code to an embedded H2 database. It seems like [RH2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RH2/index.html) is the tool to go with (library is installed) but there is no working example on the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RH2/RH2.pdf) nor on stackexchange or on Google - at least I didn't find one (besides [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328642/rh2-connect-to-h2-database-in-r)). Since I'm doing my babysteps with R, a working example to connect and retrieve data would be great!

The code must be something like

```
library(RH2)
options(RH2.jars = "C:\\h2\\bin\\h2-1.4.187.jar")
myH2 <- H2(driverClass="org.h2.Driver",
   identifier.quote="\"", jars = getOption("RH2.jars"))
con <- dbConnect(myH2,
   url = "jdbc:h2:C:\\data\\sample.h2.db", 
   user = "admin", password = "ultrasafe123")
dataFrame = fetch(dbGetQuery(con, "select * from TABLENAME"))
```

Currently I'm getting:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : 
    class not found` from `driverClass="org.h2.Driver"`
```

but that's exactly how it is shown in the documentation. Did I miss something else? A library? Including `library(RJDBC)`didn't help either.

Comment: I'm accessing the very same database with other tools (inclunding NetBeans 8.0.2. and DbVisualizer 9.2.8) successfully. I thought all it takes is the H2 driver file (`C:\h2\bin\h2-1.4.187.jar`)? Am I wrong?

Comment: So you have installed it, but you still have not given any details about its version or location on your computer, so I don't think you have provided enough information to judge the appropriateness of your attempts to construct a driver and connection .

Comment: The line `options(RH2.jars = "C:\\h2\\bin\\h2-1.4.187.jar")` tells the location and version (`1.4.187`) of the driver? What's missing? RStudio is `0.99.451`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved it for myself:

```
library(RH2)
myH2 <- H2('org.h2.Driver', 'C:/h2/bin/h2-1.4.187.jar')
## location of h2 file: C:\data\data.h2.db 
con <- dbConnect(myH2, "jdbc:h2:C:/data", "user", "password")
s <- "select * from TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'value'"
result = dbGetQuery(con, s)
dbDisconnect(con)
```